# How to handle universal links only from subdomain in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I have got a problem. There are two instances of app with different bundleID for dev and for prod. This apps can handle universal links. Problem is that where one apps trying to open link in safari, second (if they are both installed on the phone) app handles this link and open it by itself. So when one app wants to open safari another handles it and open itself. For example:

[www.dev-domain.maindomain.com/id980](http://www.dev-domain.maindomain.com/id980) - dev link
[www.prod-domain.maindomain.com/id980](http://www.prod-domain.maindomain.com/id980) - prod link

in project capabilities it's looks like applinks:*.maindomain.com
I was trying to applinks:dev-domain.maindomain.com or prod-domain.maindomain.com for different bundles but in this case handling universal links didn't works at all. AASA file located on [www.maindomain.com/apple-app-site-association](http://www.maindomain.com/apple-app-site-association)
How can I handle this situation, so prod app will handle only prod domain links and dev only dev?

Comment: Simply put the `apple-app-site-association` to all of your subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Like @congnd mentioned in the comments, you need a separate `apple-app-site-association` correctly served from both subdomains.

What got subdomain universal links working for me was *not* using the subdomain wildcard for Associated Domains in Xcode (eg applinks:*.domain.com) but instead being explicit about each supported subdomain (eg applinks:a.domain.com, applinks:b.domain.com).